# How to dynamically load content from an external url, inside of a jquery ui modal dialog widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I asked this question before, but I don't think I explained properly for what I am trying to accomplish.

There are multiple links on my website and I want to open the content from the link in a jquery ui modal dialog widget.

I'm trying to use 'this' to reference the link that the user selects dynamically.
What am I doing wrong here?

The code I'm using is below:

```
<a href="index.cs.asp?Process=comments&id=1" id="test">comment #1</a>
<a href="index.cs.asp?Process=comments&id=2" id="test">comment #2</a>
<a href="index.cs.asp?Process=comments&id=3" id="test">comment #3</a>
<div id="somediv"></div>                                    
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {  

        $("#somediv").load(this.getTrigger().attr("href")).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            modal: true
        });     
        $("#test").click(function(){$( "#somediv" ).dialog( "open" );});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/qp7NP/

A couple changes: changed ID to Class and used IFrame.

```
<a href="http://wikipedia.com/" class="test">comment #1</a><br>
<a href="http://ebay.com/" class="test">comment #2</a><br>
<a href="http://ask.com/" class="test" >comment #3</a><br>
<div id="somediv" title="this is a dialog" style="display:none;">
    <iframe id="thedialog" width="350" height="350"></iframe>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".test").click(function () {
        $("#thedialog").attr('src', $(this).attr("href"));
        $("#somediv").dialog({
            width: 400,
            height: 450,
            modal: true,
            close: function () {
                $("#thedialog").attr('src', "about:blank");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

In case you want to pull in the HTML instead of IFrame, you will have to use Ajax (XMLHttpRequest), something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qp7NP/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! http://jsfiddle.net/qp7NP/ this one does what I want. Except that it does not take the style from the main page. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: IFRAME is a stand-alone HTML document. It has to have <html> and <head> sections. So just add the <link href="/MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> line to the <head> section.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple elements with the same Id. 
Change your links to to `class="test"` instead and therefore your click event to `$('.test').click()`.

Also if you still have problems, and I remember I had some similar issues because how JQUery Dialog behaves itself with the DOM. It will literally rip your #somediv out of content and append it to the bottom of a page to display that dialog. I solved my dynamic dialog loading issues with wrapping it in another div.

```
<div id="somediv-wrap">
  <div id="somediv">

  </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  

        $("#somediv-wrap").dialog({
                  autoOpen: false,
                   width: 400, 
                   height:200,
                   modal: true
                  });  

        $(".test").click(function(event)
          {
              event.preventDefault();
              var link = $(this).attr('href');

              $("#somediv").load(link,function(){
               $( "#somediv-wrap" ).dialog( "open" );   
              });                        
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Shenaniganz I see that you edited the code, but I still couldnt make it work on jsfiddle.