# How to hide a transient web page once it's been used?

Tags: javascript, web

I have the following situation

- Home Page -- User clicks a link, which directs them to a JS-generated page, which may be time intensive
- JS-page does some work and may display a "timer" saying work will be done in X seconds, and redirects user to a PDF
- PDF page is shown to the user

**Problem:**

Once the user is done with PDF, they click "Back" button on the browser, hoping to go back to Home Page, but instead they go to JS page, as that's how browsers work -- they step back once.  Naturally that displays the timer again and redirects users right back to PDF.

How do I structure my software so that when users are done with PDF, clicking Back (or some other simple way) takes them back to the Home Page?

Simple work-around is for users to click back twice in quick succession, but that's kind of inconvenient - breaks usability of this particular piece for the users and I don't want to do that.

**EDIT For Code:**

PHP side:

```
      case "export-to-pdf":

        $printpdf->generateCanvasInBrowser();
        break;
```

HTML/JS side:

```
public function generateCanvasInBrowser()
{
    //generate form with data

    //submit form to PHP script
    document.forms['form'].submit();
}
```

PHP-side:

```
//Takes and processes POST-ed data from form, and generates PDF
<?
echo printPDF();
```

**EDIT For solution try:**

I did a modal dialog with Java Script (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15582060/2883328), and now JS page shows up in an overlay div, but then also does the PDF. It shows up in the dialog box, not in the main browser.  It looks fair enough, but still breaks expected functionality for the user as they are used to clicking back from PDF to home page.  With this one I'll need to find a way to submit the form AND get out of the modal box.

Comment: What do you use to redirect the viewers? Just a `document.location.href = ''`?

Comment: I use a form submit, so `document.forms['my_form'].submit();`

Comment: could you please show some code, like a working example? I'm not quite sure I understand what you're doing, so I can't really find the cause of your problem at the moment. For example, if you can, link me to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo that demonstrates your problem, or if that doesn't work, a link to your site.

Comment: see my edit.  I'll see if I can make a fiddle

Comment: And something else, why do you need to first redirect the user to the JS-generated page? Can't you display the countdown on the home page itself? That would avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: I could maybe do an overlay div.  Have not made one before really but maybe it could work.

Comment: I did a modal dialog with Java Script (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15582060/2883328), and now JS page shows up in an overlay dif, but then also does the PDF.  I need to find a way to submit the form AND get out of the modal box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(moving over from my comment, which seemed to fix the problem mostly)*

The best way to fix this is to display the countdown on the home page itself. That would avoid the problem altogether, because then you wouldn't load any page in between. If you use a modal, for example, which contains the js-generated page, then you will need to make sure to submit the form to the top page. You can do that by adding `target="_top"` to your `<form>` tag.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: alright thanks! that seemed to have worked, with minimal pain.  
I did the `target="_top"` way.  I am not sure if in-page will be best due to the nature of my UI -- doing a pop-up "Please Wait" seems to make sense to me more.  In-page way may be cool, but maybe for later :)

Answer (score 1):

Generate the JS Page INSIDE A DIV in the Home page and work widh "visibility: collapse" to show or hide .if you use JQuery use ("#div").hide() and .show()

That should be a lot easier and solve your problem